# What's an "anOperation()" in this Factory Method diagram?

Tags: design-patterns, diagram, factory-method

I'm learning about the factory method pattern and its wikipedia page has the following diagram:

http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plik:Factory_Method_UML_class_diagram.svg

It's pretty simple so I understand everything except one thing - what is that mysterious `anOperation()` method? What does it do? More importantly - is it part of the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking down the Wiki page that uses that figure, you'll find the [Google translation from Japanese](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fja.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFactory_Method_%25E3%2583%2591%25E3%2582%25BF%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2583%25B3&edit-text=&act=url) as follows:

> Here, anOperation calls the factoryMethod, to obtain an instance of a subclass of the Product, be used.

I can't think of a real-world example of factory method that actually does this, however. The Java [iterator() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator--) in Collections is a factory method that does not use anOperation() as some intermediate step. I don't see anOperation as a fundamental part of that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do anything. It is simply an example of the annotation used to represent methods in this type of diagram.

Comment: Is it in some way part of the pattern?

Comment: I highly doubt that the name is significant in any way. I don't see how having an extra arbitrary operation would be significant for the pattern, either.